# Applet does not appear

Tags: user-interface

After I compile this code, and I go to run it. The applet will just not appear, what is wrong with it? I'm not the best with programming and I just need a little clarity on why this is not running! I cannot submit the image to this program for I am a new user by the way

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class Exercise17_09 extends JFrame {
    private ImageIcon icGrapes = new ImageIcon("C:\temp");  
    private JPanel top;
private JPanel bottom;
private JPanel text;
private JPanel align;
private JPanel txtcom;
private JPanel lblpane;
    private JPanel lblpnl;
private JPanel AlignPanel;
    private JLabel jlblGrapes;
    private JLabel jlbltwo;
private JLabel jlblthree;
    private JLabel jlblfour;
private JLabel jlblfive;
    private JComboBox jcboone;
    private JComboBox jcbotwo;
private JComboBox jcbothree;
    private JComboBox jcbofour;




public static void main(String[] args) {
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    Exercise17_09 inst = new Exercise17_09();
    inst.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    inst.setVisible(true);
        }});
}//end main

public Exercise17_09() {
    super();
    initGUI();
}

private void initGUI() {
    try {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    {
        top = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        top.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(392, 122));

                    {
                    jlblGrapes = new JLabel("Grapes", icGrapes, SwingConstants.CENTER);
                    jlblGrapes.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(392,122));
                    jlblGrapes.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);


        }
        }//end 

            {
        bottom = new JPanel();
        GridLayout BottomPanelLayout = new GridLayout(1, 2);
        BottomPanelLayout.setHgap(5);
        BottomPanelLayout.setVgap(5);
        BottomPanelLayout.setColumns(2);
        bottom.setLayout(BottomPanelLayout);
        getContentPane().add(bottom, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        bottom.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(392, 130));

                    {
        AlignPanel = new JPanel();
        BorderLayout AlignPanelLayout = new BorderLayout();
        bottom.add(AlignPanel);
        AlignPanel.setLayout(AlignPanelLayout);
        AlignPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null,  

  "Horizontal Alignment", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP));
                {
        lblpnl = new JPanel();
        GridLayout jPanel1Layout = new GridLayout(2, 1);
        jPanel1Layout.setHgap(5);
        jPanel1Layout.setVgap(5);
        jPanel1Layout.setColumns(1);
        jPanel1Layout.setRows(2);
        AlignPanel.add(lblpnl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        lblpnl.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);

                    {
        jlblfive = new JLabel();
        lblpnl.add(jlblfive);
        jlblfive.setText("Horizontal");
                    }

                    {
        jlblfour = new JLabel();
        lblpnl.add(jlblfour);
        jlblfour.setText("Vertical");
                    }
                }

                                    {
        align = new JPanel();
        GridLayout AligncomboLayout = new GridLayout(2, 1);
        AligncomboLayout.setHgap(5);
                    AligncomboLayout.setVgap(5);
        AligncomboLayout.setColumns(1);
        AligncomboLayout.setRows(2);
        AlignPanel.add(align, BorderLayout.EAST);
        align.setLayout(AligncomboLayout);
                    {
        ComboBoxModel jcboHAModel = 
        new DefaultComboBoxModel(
        new String[] { "LEFT", "CENTER", "RIGHT" });
        jcbofour = new JComboBox();
        align.add(jcbofour);
        jcbofour.setModel(jcboHAModel);
                    }

                                            {
        ComboBoxModel jcboVAModel = 
        new DefaultComboBoxModel(
        new String[] { "TOP", "CENTER", "BOTTOM" });
        jcbothree = new JComboBox();
        align.add(jcbothree);
        jcbothree.setModel(jcboVAModel);
                    }
                }
            }

                    {
        text = new JPanel();
        BorderLayout TextPanelLayout = new BorderLayout();
        bottom.add(text);
        text.setLayout(TextPanelLayout);
        text.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Text Position"));

                    {
        lblpane = new JPanel();
        GridLayout Label2panelLayout = new GridLayout(2, 1);
        Label2panelLayout.setHgap(5);
        Label2panelLayout.setVgap(5);
        Label2panelLayout.setColumns(1);
        Label2panelLayout.setRows(2);
        text.add(lblpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        lblpane.setLayout(Label2panelLayout);

                    {
        jlblthree = new JLabel();
        lblpane.add(jlblthree);
        jlblthree.setText("Horizontal");
        }

                    {
        jlbltwo = new JLabel();
        lblpane.add(jlbltwo);
        jlbltwo.setText("Vertical");
        }
        }

                    {
        txtcom = new JPanel();
            GridLayout TextComboLayout = new GridLayout(2, 1);
        TextComboLayout.setHgap(5);
        TextComboLayout.setVgap(5);
        TextComboLayout.setColumns(1);
        TextComboLayout.setRows(2);
        txtcom.setLayout(TextComboLayout);
        text.add(txtcom, BorderLayout.EAST);

                    {
        ComboBoxModel jcboTHAModel = 
        new DefaultComboBoxModel(
        new String[] { "LEFT", "CENTER", "RIGHT" });
        jcbotwo = new JComboBox();
        txtcom.add(jcbotwo);
        jcbotwo.setModel(jcboTHAModel);
        jcbotwo.setSelectedItem("CENTER");

        }

                    {
        ComboBoxModel jcboTVAModel = 
        new DefaultComboBoxModel(
        new String[] { "TOP", "CENTER", "BOTTOM" });
        jcboone = new JComboBox();
        txtcom.add(jcboone);
        jcboone.setModel(jcboTVAModel);
        jcboone.setSelectedItem("CENTER");
        }
        }
        }

                    jcbofour.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {


     public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

    String A = (String)jcbofour.getSelectedItem();
    if(A.equals("LEFT"))    {
        jlblGrapes.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
                    }
    else if(A.equals("CENTER")) {
        jlblGrapes.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                    }
    else if(A.equals("RIGHT"))  {
        jlblGrapes.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
                    }
                }
            });

    jcbothree.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            String A = (String)jcbothree.getSelectedItem();
            if(A.equals("TOP")) {
            jlblGrapes.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
                    }
                else if(A.equals("CENTER")) {
            jlblGrapes.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                    }
                else if(A.equals("BOTTOM")) {
            jlblGrapes.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
                    }
                }
            });


   jcbotwo.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
              String A = (String)jcbotwo.getSelectedItem();
              if(A.equals("LEFT"))  {
              jlblGrapes.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.LEFT);
                    }
              else if(A.equals("CENTER"))   {
              jlblGrapes.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                    }
              else if(A.equals("RIGHT"))    {
              jlblGrapes.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
                    }
                }
            });

       jcboone.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        String A = (String)jcboone.getSelectedItem();
        if(A.equals("TOP")) {
        jlblGrapes.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.TOP);
                    }
        else if(A.equals("CENTER")) {
        jlblGrapes.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                    }
        else if(A.equals("BOTTOM")) {
        jlblGrapes.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
                    }
    }
    });

    }
pack();
setSize(400, 300);
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();



}

}

}
```

Comment: This is a lot of code to look through. What error(s) do you receive? What have you tried so far? Consider focusing on a particular section of code where you think the problem might be.

Comment: Well once I compile it in netbeans,